# The characters in my HTML saved from DOMdocument become escaped

Tags: php, html, dom

I have an irritating problem using PHP's DOMdocument. I have loaded HTML, and changed some of the element's attributes. I want to save the changed HTML, and output it. 
The strange thing is, when I use `->saveHTML()` or `->saveXML()` my closing tags' slashes become escaped. I could remove the escaping with regex, but I would like to know if there is any cleaner way...

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML ($roosterHTML);
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            libxml_clear_errors();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

            $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
            $cols = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('td');
            $name = preg_replace("/(\\n|\\r| )/", "", $cols->item(3)->nodeValue);
            $sirname = preg_replace("/(\\n|\\r| )/", "", $cols->item(2)->nodeValue);
            $class = preg_replace("/(\\n|\\r| )/", "", $cols->item(1)->nodeValue);
            $header =  "Rooster van $name $sirname ($class)";

            $rooster = $tables->item(1);
            $firstRow = true;
            foreach ($rooster->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $row) {
                if ($firstRow) {
                    $firstRow = false;
                    continue;
                }
                $firstCol = true;
                foreach ($row->getElementsByTagName('td') as $col) {
                    if ($firstCol) {
                        $firstCol = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    $text = $col->nodeValue;
                    $col->setAttribute('style','background-color:#FF0');
                    //$return.= $text;
                }
            }

            $rooster = $dom->saveXML($rooster);
```

Testing (just click submit, to send a POST value): 
http://bit.ly/ymK3DA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the escaped is caused by the json
which mean this page is not output HTML but json-alike plain text

Comment: Thanks, I was about to close this question, I just noticed that too.